# How to wrap a number using mod operator

Tags: algorithm, modulo

Not sure if this is possible, but is there an automatic way, using mod or something similiar, to automatically correct bad input values? For example:

```
If r>255, then set r=255 and
if r<0, then set r=0
```

So basically what I'm asking is whats a clever mathematical way to set this rather than using

```
if(r>255)
 r=255;
if(r<0)
 r=0;
```

Comment: For future answerers, I think the asker is trying to do this without conditionals. Which means no MAX or MIN function calls allowed.

Comment: Well I was thinking there would be a cool mathematical approach to it, but I guess any unique shortcut works, even though MIN and MAX are pretty much conditionals..

Comment: Are you just curious or looking for a speed gain or better aesthetics?

Comment: Wrap is something different. This operation is called *saturation* or *clamping*.

Comment: I agree with @ruslik. Can the title of the question be changed to remove the word "wrap" which can use modulo as an elegant mathematical solution? Otherwise people like me will keep getting here looking for the wrap answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
r = std:max(0, std::min(r, 255));
```

Answer (score 2):

The following function will output what you are looking for:

```
 f(x) = (510*(1 + Sign[-255 + x]) + x*(1 + Sign[255 - x])*(1 + Sign[x]))/4
```

As shown here:

[image]

Comment: So how are you implementing Sign :-)

Comment: @stefan Many ways to do that, if it's not a primitive. For example Sign[x]=x/Abs[x] (for x != 0)

Comment: @belisarius i Agree with Kdoto >D But with Mathematica at hands i guess we could sit here all Millenium ;-)

Comment: @stefan Is it _that_ bad ? :D

Comment: @belisarius Mathematica? Indeed it is. I have this gigantical PDF where i didn't really know what to find from some nasty iterative integrals. When Mathematica threw "\\[Pi]" as answer I died for a month.

Comment: @stefan There is a very nice and helpful community of Mathematica users here in SO. Don't hesitate to ask any question you have under the [mathematica] tag

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like --

```
R = MIN(r, 255);
R = MAX(R, 0);
```

Comment: That wouldn't work. `R` would always be zero or a negative number.

Comment: You got MIN and MAX the wrong way around. The result is always 0.

Comment: Even if this works, it's not really answering the question. MAX and MIN have conditionals, which the asker is trying to avoid.

Comment: @Kdoto: I am not sure the standard specifies how min/max are implemented. The OP asked for a clever mathematical way. min/max are relatively standard mathematical functions. I doubt the question is about speed and more about aesthetics.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your hardware and possibly how your interpreter deal with ints, you can do this:

Assuming that an unsigned int is 16 bits (to keep my masks short):

```
r = r & 0000000011111111;
```

If an int was 32 bits, you'd need 16 more zeros at the start of the bit mask.

After that bitwise AND, the maximum value r can have is 255. Depending on the hardware, an unsigned int might do something odd given a value below zero. I believe that case is already handled by the bitmask (at least on the hardware that I've used). If not, you can do `r = min(r, 0);` first.

Comment: You are assuming stuff not meantioned in the question. You dont know how the number is described binary.

Comment: I guess so. This is the only answer I see so far that offers an efficiency gain, rather than just aesthetic gain. So I thought it was worth mentioning. You're right though -- I do assume that r is stored in a finite, maskable form -- which is the case for every question I've ever seen on SO. I did write "Assuming that an unsigned int is 16 bits" in my answer :)

Comment: If it makes you feel better, you can apply this same logic to a number stored with infinitely many digits, as long as you know what structure the number is represented as, and can form a mask against that number.

Comment: @Kdoto Just so you know. It wasnt me who downvoted your post.

Comment: @stefan, Thanks. I didn't assume you did.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem when dealing with images. For some special values (like these ones, 0 and 255) you can use this nonportable method:

```
static inline int trim_8bit(unsigned i){
    return 0xff & ((i | -!!(i & ~0xff))) + (i >> 31);
    // where "0xff &" can be omitted if you return unsigned char
};
```

In real cases the clamping have to be performed rarely, so that you could write

```
static inline unsigned char trim_8bit_v2(unsigned i){   
    if (__builtin_expect(i & ~0xFF, 0)) // it's for gcc, use __assume for MSVC
        return (i >> 31) - 1; 
    return i;
};
```

And to be sure which is fastest, measure.